# OnClickListener for list view?

Tags: android, listview, dialog

How can I insert an `OnClickListener` for list view? I want to show an alert dialog with two buttons, "yes" and "no", when I click an item.

```
private void loadListViewData() {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        lables);

    listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set Click Listener on item, then use `setOnItemClickListener`, on listview, using this method you will have access to clicked item position too, simply do as below:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View convertView, int position, long id)
    {
         //Do some operation
    }
});
```